# append circle to map in d3

Tags: d3.js, map-projections

I've created a map in d3 and need to append a series of circles to it.  I've tried to get just one circle to show and can't.  I've also changed the size of the circle.  Dev tools shows a circle on the page but it won't show.  Here is my code:

The circle is placed in the center of the map.

```
var features = parsedJSON.features;

mapLayer.selectAll('path')
    .data(features)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
    .attr('fill', '#e8edfc')
    .select('svg').enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx',-106.661513 )
    .attr('cy', 35.05917399 )
    .attr('r','10px')
    .style('fill', 'red');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are appending a circle to a path element, which can't be done in SVG. Better practice would be create a group element ("g") per feature, and append paths, circles etc to that, for example your code above should be:

```
    let feature = mapLayer.selectAll('.path')
        .data(features)
        .enter()
        .append('g')

     feature.append('path)
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
        .attr('fill', '#e8edfc')

    feature.append('circle')
        .attr('cx',-106.661513 )
        .attr('cy', 35.05917399 )
        .attr('r','10px')
        .style('fill', 'red');
```

If you are adding more than one circle, you will need to change the parts that assign cx, cy, and r to use the appended data, eg

```
feature.append('circle')
            .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d.value); })
            etc
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this probably did it for a simple reason: how many circles do you think your code is appending (one right over the other)?

Comment: I answered the questions at hand :) "I've tried to get just one circle to show and can't."

Comment: Do you think your answer appends just one circle?

Comment: You still didn't show OP how to append just **one** circle. Your code appends several circles (`features.length`) at the same position (which was wrongly specified by OP).

Comment: I've +1 just because the answer starts with 0

"You are appending a circle to a path element, which can't be done in SVG"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `cx` and `cy` values...

```
.attr('cx',-106.661513 )
.attr('cy', 35.05917399 )
```

... don't seem to be actual SVG coordinates, but **longitude and latitude** instead. In that case, you have to use your projection (here I'm assuming it is named `projection`):

```
.attr('cx', projection([-106.661513, 35.05917399])[0])
.attr('cy', projection([-106.661513, 35.05917399])[1])
```

Second, you cannot append a circle to a path. Use your `mapLayer` selection:

```
mapLayer.append("circle")   
    .attr('cx', projection([-106.661513, 35.05917399])[0])
    .attr('cy', projection([-106.661513, 35.05917399])[1])
    .attr('r','10px')
    .style('fill', 'red');
```